# Redirect in angular not going to the correct page after authguard

Tags: angular, redirect, auth-guard

I've got a structure for redirection after log in in which we are sent to a page which tells the user to log in, after log in a service tries to redirect the user to the page they were trying to visit before the redirection. I keep the page visited in an observable.
The redirection happens after the assignment of new tokens and refresh tokens

It looks like this

Authguard Service:

```
async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
console.log("ENTERING THE GUARD")
if (!this.storage.getToken() || !this.storage.isLoggedInfunc()) {
  console.log("doesn't have token")
  if (this.storage.getToken()) {
    const refreshing = await this.auth.tryRefreshingTokens();
    if (refreshing && this.storage.isLoggedInfunc()) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      this.storage.setValueLastPage(this.router.url);
      this.router.navigate(['needlogin']);
      console.log("Returning from inside 1");
      return false;
    }
  }
  else {
    this.storage.setValueLastPage(this.router.url);
    this.router.navigate(['needlogin']);
    console.log("Returning from inside 2");
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(this.router.url)
debugger
console.log("Gets into the true part")
console.log(state.url);
return true;
```

}
}

Storage Service:

```
  public saveUser(user: any): void {
this.getValueLastPage().subscribe(value => {
  this.LastPageThis = value;
});
this.cookieService.delete(JWT_TOKEN)
this.cookieService.set(JWT_TOKEN, user.token);
delete user.token;
window.localStorage.removeItem(REFRESH_TOKEN);
window.localStorage.setItem(REFRESH_TOKEN, user.refreshToken);
delete user.refreshToken;
window.localStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
this.setValueLoggedIn(true);
console.log(this.router.url)
if (this.router.url.includes("/needlogin") && this.LastPageThis !== null) {
  console.log(this.LastPageThis);
  this.navigateback(this.LastPageThis);
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['/'])
}
```

}

The problem is it sends me to the `needlogin page` instead of say '', but when I check the url on the state in the authguard '' appears.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Angular Guards should return an URLTree to navigate user to another page. What you are doing here is, starting a new navigation by calling "router.navigate" method and blocking the previous one by returning false. This might be a cause of conflict. See: https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/